# Using ionic custom elements in standard custom elements

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I wonder if someone already run into the following issue:

I am trying to use ion custom elements in standard custom elements, but the ion custom elements do not seem to work properly when used within the shadow root.

I created a small test that shows the problem
both custom elements should render a black button, but only the UsingInnerHtml element works as expected, the UsingShadowRoot renders a transparent button no matter which color value I provide

```js
class UsingInnerHtml extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `
      <ion-button color="dark">Click me</ion-button>
    `;
  }
}


const template = document.createElement('template');

template.innerHTML = `
  <ion-button color="dark">Click me</ion-button>
`;

class UsingShadowRoot extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}


customElements.define('using-shadow-root', UsingShadowRoot);
customElements.define('using-inner-html', UsingInnerHtml);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
        <!-- styles -->
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Libs -->
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
         <script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@latest/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@latest/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        shadow root
        <using-shadow-root></using-shadow-root>
      </div>
      <div>
         inner html
        <using-inner-html></using-inner-html>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```